# In CF10, why do structure members become undefined?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

The code below has some unexpected behavior in CF10 especially when compared to CF8 (I haven't tried in CF9).

Line 6 causes some previously defined structure members to become undefined.  Why?  Is this a bug or did I miss a memo?

```
<cfset struct = structNew()>
<cfset struct["x.foo"] = 1>            <!--- LINE 2 --->
<cfset struct["x.bar"] = 2>            <!--- LINE 3 --->
<cfdump var="#struct#" label="before"> <!--- struct["x.foo"] & struct["x.bar"] have values (they're defined) at this point --->

<cfset struct["x"] = structNew()>      <!--- LINE 6: in CF10 struct["x.foo"] & struct["x.bar"] become undefined --->
<cfdump var="#struct#" label="after">

<h3>Coldfusion Version</h3>
#server.coldfusion.productversion#
```

[image: Coldfusion 10 output] 
[image: Coldfusion 8 output]

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I have found over the years, that ColdFusion becomes less tolerent of imperfect code as it gets upgraded.  The sample code has bad logic.  Version 8 obviously let you get away with it.  Version 10 does not.

Comment: @DanBracuk - _sample code has bad logic_ : where?

Comment: The line 2,3, and 6 combination is bad logic.

Comment: @SeanCoyne - I agree 100%.  I don't expect the addition of the 3rd key (`x`) to mangle the values of the first two keys.

Comment: @DanBracuk - _line 2,3, and 6 combination is bad logic_ - if you have time, please explain why.

Comment: @AdrianWright - I think Adam's blog entry hit the nail on the head: *".. the dump can't see the value .... But the value is actually there.*" ie If you output #struct["x.bar"]#, it will display "2".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are experiencing what I document on my blog? "[Odd behaviour with struct keys with dots in their names](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2014/04/odd-behaviour-with-struct-keys-with.html)".

It's a bit late to be raising regressions that impact ColdFusion 8, but you could raise a ticket with Adobe if you wanted. They'll probbaly just ignore it though.

Other than that, the only salient reaction is kinda "well now you know". Sorry :-/